# Объявление классов перегрузкой

Tags: php, ооп, классы, наследование

Привет, народ!
Я пишу приложение на PHP, и мне необходимо объявить внешние классы, написав при этом гибкий механизм подключения. Я остановился на перегрузке свойств и методов + наследование, но запутался настолько, что теперь даже не знаю, возможно ли такое?

Имею следующее:

Класс-родитель - Bootstrap.php:

```
class Bootstrap implements Gateway
{
    protected $object = [];
    protected $data = [];

    public function init()
    {
        $this->config = new Config();
        $this->log = new Logging('Logging initialized');
        $this->debug = new Debug();
        $this->router = new Router($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $this->lang = new Lang(
            $this->router->get('language');
        );
        $this->db = new DB(
            $this->config->get('db_host'),
            $this->config->get('db_user'),
            $this->config->get('db_password'),
            $this->config->get('db_name')
        );
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->object[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->object)) {
            return $this->object[$name];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

И класс-наследник - Router.php:

```
class Router extends Bootstrap
{
    protected $url;

    public function __construct($url)
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->url = urldecode(ltrim($url, '/'));

        $languages = $this->config->get('languages');
        $routes = $this->config->get('routes');

        ...
    }
}
```

А проблема в том, что при вызове parent::init(), классы "переобъявляются". И что с этим делать - я не знаю. Можно ли просто взять свойства вызова, не вызывая сами классы (точнее их конструкторы)? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: что значит класс переобъявляется при вызове  parent::init()? Теоретически, если в классе Router есть метод init(), то при вызове  parent::init() из Router просто вызовется метод init() из родительского класса Bootstrap.

Comment: метод "переобъявляется" тогда, если вы внутри класса Router создадите метод init(), который уже существует в родительском классе Bottstrap.

Comment: Это значит, что конструкторы классов рекурсивно вызываются, если я напишу `parent::init()`. Пока что это единственный способ получения свойств из родительского класса, который я знаю.

Comment: это не рекурсия, просто вызов из родительского/базового класса.

Comment: Но мы так и не поняли - в чем проблема?

Comment: В том, что мне нужен доступ к перегруженным свойствам класса `Bootstrap`, а не вызов метода с этими свойствами. См. две последние строчки в классе `Router`: они вызовут ошибку, что перегруженное свойство `$config` не найдена в массиве `$object[]` класса `Bootstrap`.

Comment: Что есть свойства вызова? В данном коде просто при инициализации дочернего класса сработает метод `init` в родительском. Все неперегруженные(читай: неперезаписанные в дочернем классе) методы(функции) будут браться из родительского. Попробуй `var_dump'нуть` весь объект, после инициализции дочернего класса, посмотри что там возвращается.

Answer (score 3):

> Я пишу приложение на PHP, и мне необходимо объявить внешние классы,
>   написав при этом гибкий механизм подключения. Я остановился на
>   перегрузке свойств и методов + наследование, но запутался настолько,
>   что теперь даже не знаю, возможно ли такое?

Советую посмотреть, как подобные вещи реализованны в современных фреймворках (и лучше будет взять один из этих фреймворков в качестве каркаса для Вашего приложения на PHP). Вашу реализацию нельзя назвать ни гибкой, ни удобной (ни рабочей). 
Из того, что вижу я, Вы пытаетесь реализовать некое подобие сборки приложения с внедрением зависимостей. Поэтому советую также погуглить *Dependency Injection* и то, как собирать приложение с помощью контейнера внедрения зависимостей.

Также рекоммендую разобраться в базовой теории ООП. Почему Вы решили, что `Router` является наследником `Bootstrap`? Какая зона ответственности у каждого из Ваших классов? Зачем `Router`'у, который по идее должен заниматься маршрутизацией входящих запросов в Вашем приложении, быть еще и сборщиком Вашего приложения (а если Вы унаследовали `Router` от `Bootstrap`, то он у Вас является `Bootstrap`'ом)? Если Вы хотите, чтобы в `Router` было доступно поведение, которое Вы до этого описали в `Bootstrap`, и Вы не хотите копипастить куски кода из одного класса в другой, то наследование - это лишь *один из* способов повторного использования кода, при чем зачастую применяемый разработчиками абсолютно не к месту (как в Вашем случае). Если Вам из `Router`'а необходим доступ к защищенным данным `Bootstrap` - это тоже не повод строить промеж этих ребят иерархию наследования. Не пытаетесь ли Вы нарушить таким образом инкапсуляцию? Не лучше ли было бы описать нормальный публичный интерфейс `Bootstrap`, используя который клиенты класса смогли бы его нормально опросить и получить необходимую им для работы информацию. Если Вам от `Bootstrap` необходим только `Config`, почему бы его не передать прямо в
конструктор `Router`?

При этом не забывайте, что, наследуя `Router` от `Bootstrap`, Вы жестко завязываетесь на конкретной реализации `Bootstrap`, т.е. изменения в классе сборщика могут поломать Вам работу маршрутизатора.

> См. две последние строчки в классе Router: они вызовут ошибку, что
>   перегруженное свойство $config не найдена в массиве $object[] класса
>   Bootstrap

Ошибка у Вас (судя по коду, который Вы показали) вылезет не из-за этого. Приложение уйдет у Вас в бесконечный цикл: *в методе `Bootstrap::init()` вы создаете новый экземпляр `Router`, который внутри своего конструктора вызывает родительский метод `init()`, внутри которого создается новый Router,  который внутри своего конструктора вызывает родительский метод `init()`, внутри которого создается новый Router,  который внутри своего конструктора вызывает родительский метод `init()`, внутри которого создается новый Router,...* Вы же понимаете, что если `Router` унаследован от `Bootstrap`, то какой-то конкретный `$router` не будет наследником какого либо конкретного экземпляра `$bootstrap`? Т.е. когда Вы вызываете у какого то `$bootstrap->init()`, то `$bootstrap` не будет "папой" того экземпляра `$router`, который будет создан внутри его метода через оператор `new`. `$bootstrap` ведь не выступает у Вас прототипом для создания `$router`.

Ваш код заработает, если переписать `Bootstrap::init()`:

```
public function init(Router $router = null)
{
    //...
    if (!$router) {
        $router = new Router($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
    $this->router = $router;
    //...
}
```

И вызов `init` из конструктора `Router`: `parent::init($this)`.

Или если конструктор `Router` переписать так, чтобы он принимал `Bootstrap`; или `Config`, если Вам только он и нужен от сборщика; или сразу `$languages` и `$routes`.

Накостылить и завести все это дело можно, но только делать этого не нужно, потому что по хорошему нужно переписывать полностью все.

Хотите сделать приложение на PHP? Берите буквально любой фреймворк и пилите на нем, почитывая мануалы, и изучая мат.часть.

> Можно ли просто взять свойства вызова, не вызывая сами классы (точнее
>   их конструкторы)?

Можно взять статические свойства класса, для доступа к ним не нужно создавать экземпляры класса. Ваши свойства не объявленны как статические, соответственно получить конкретно их, не создавая экземпляр класса, не получится.

Вообще, похоже на то, что, когда Вы писали этот код, то мыслили статическими классами, а не классами и их конкретными экземплярами. И это плохо.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, Игорь. Вообще, пока что, я не хочу использовать фреймворки, в них нужно разбираться, а тут мне посоветовали написать пару своих приложений (подобия фреймворков), дабы понимать их составляющую основу.

Comment: Ранее, у меня была конструкция следующего вида: класс приложения (App) статический, в нем присутствовал метод `getRouter`, в котором было создание объекта `$router = new Router();`. Так вызывалась маршрутизация в нужный момент времени, не заполняя класс `Router` лишним: `App::getRouter->getUrl();`. Но затем я понял, чтобы делать так с остальными классами, необходимо каждый раз писать метод get... необходимо было создать механизм, который бы крутил методы "на лету". Но перегрузка работает лишь с нестатическими методами и свойствами, поэтому пришлось прибегнуть к наследованию такими извращениями

Answer (score 0):

> В том, что мне нужен доступ к перегруженным свойствам класса Bootstrap, а не вызов метода с этими свойствами. См. две последние строчки в классе Router: они вызовут ошибку, что перегруженное свойство $config не найдена в массиве $object[] класса Bootstrap. – Mistress Denna 13 дек в 19:08

не воспроизводится:
[sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bed903a97dee67541754a7be0f254d6b4a7a9d76)

Answer (score -1):

> А проблема в том, что при вызове parent::init(), классы "переобъявляются".

ошибка здесь у вас: каждый раз при создании нового объекта Router или Bootstrap в вашем коде будут создаваться свойства, к которым по значению будут присваиваться вновь созданные объекты классов:Config, Logging, Debug, Router, Lang. Если предполагается что ваше приложение должно однажды инициировать объект класса Config и в дальнейшем использовать только этот объект, то у вас ошибка и работать будет очень не экономично. По хорошему, вместо new ClassName; делают ClassName::getInstance(); и функция возвращают ссылку на уже созданный instance (объект) и создает Instance только в случае если ссылки не существует.

В PHP нет перегрузки - это факт! поддержка ООП в php реализована с ограничением, есть вариант реализации перегрузки  [PhpManual Перегрузка](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php). но это далеко от классического понимания перегрузки. Под перегрузкой методов в классическом понимании подразумевают различную реализацию в классе метода method() и method(arg1), и компилятор должен понимать, что в одном случае вызывается один метод в другом случае другой метод, такой реализации перезагрузки в php нет, также как и нет возможности написать реализацию метода для разных типов данных, хотелось бы иметь возможность сделать так:

```
function method( $arg1 as BootStrap){...}
function method( $arg1 as Router){...}
```

но в php таких возможностей нет, так что... по хорошему php это функциональный язык - язык последовательно выполняемых сценариев, не нужно от него ожидать что-то больше.

Comment: а в чем проблема вызывать метод `function($arg){ if($arg instanceof BootStrap){...}}` ?

Comment: ммм, а ваш вопрос имеет отношение к теме "Перезагрузка"? просто реализовать можно все что угодно написать очень много if else и все вроде бы хорошо. только к ООП это несколько отношения не имеет

Comment: Ну, цитата _Под перезагрузкой методов в классическом понимании подразумевают различную реализацию в классе метода method() и method(arg1), и компилятор должен понимать, что в одном случае вызывается один метод в другом случае другой метод_ в пхп решаемо. И если это делается отлично от привычного вам метода, это еще не значит, что это неправильно.

Comment: в смысле? где вы прочитали что оцениваю ситуацию с позиции правильно или неправильно? я говорю что этого нет и не следует от php ожидать большего...

Comment: _Под перезагрузкой методов в классическом понимании подразумевают различную реализацию в классе метода method() и method(arg1)_ ; _такой реализации перезагрузки в php нет_. Да, есть другая реализация, прекрасно работающая. Которая отработает так, как и написано у вас в ответе, которую, очевидно вы не видите правильной. К ООП форма записи вообще мало отношения имеет.

Comment: Я не говорю, что у php идеальный алгоритм реализации принципов ООП. Но я говорю, что в php есть возможность перегрузить функции, да с другим синтаксисом, но это не делает эту возможность "недоступно", или использование ее - неправильным. Я цитирую ваши потому что хочу выделить контекст обсуждения, потому что вы пишете одно, хотя в реализации мы получаем совсем другое.

Comment: Читайте про полиморфизм. перегрузка или перезагрузка метода,  как реализация полиморфизма,  подразумевает что в классе есть возможность объявить один и тот же метод для разных контекстов (набора и состава аргуметов метода) и в зависимости от контекста компилятор выбирает какой из описанных в классе методов использовать. И конкретно этого в php нет! нет никакой перегрузки, нет никакой поддержки полиморфизма. А то что вы можете написать один метод и в рамках метода определить контекст используя конструкции if else это нельзя назвать перегрузкой.